# DocuSign Console within iFrame

Tags: docusignapi

I'm currently trying to place the docusign console onto my website. My current method is using an iFrame but I'm wondering if that is secure and the optimal way of doing it. I was also wondering if the docusignAPI has a solution to that implemented already because I couldn't find one after playing around on the website with various code sources.

Preferably, users would be able to go to some part of the website, view the contract or document they need to sign on the website without having the leave the website. This includes viewing the document on the website as well such as using an iFrame allows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using iframes to host DocuSign embedded signing is not a good idea for a few reasons.

1. Typically to have a good experience it is recommended to use a large window.
2. Security Concerns. The users of your app wouldn't be able to see the DocuSign URL as well as the green check to know they're using a secure website which should make them feel more confident about using your integration.